# How can i clearInterval(myFunc) after myFunc has executed 5 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The purpose of the code below is to alert online shoppers that they must select a color (via a select/option menu) before putting an item into their basket. If they don't select a color (ie, make a selection) some blinking text displays alerting them.

I'm trying to have the text blink 3 times then stop. I tried using some counter vars but didn't work. How can I re-write this so the blink executes 3 times only?

```
function blink() {
    if ($('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'hidden')
    }
}

function showNotice() {  
    timerId = setInterval(blink, 200);
} 

$('#addToCart').click(function() {
    if ($("select > option:first").is(":selected")) {
        showNotice();
    } else  {
        clearInterval(showNotice);
        $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
})
```

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to express by `function showNotice() { ... } else { ... }`? That's not a thing.

Comment: And clearInterval takes identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel, i.e the ID  returned from setInterval().. not the function itself..!

Comment: By the way, your `blink` function is a reinvention of [`jQuery.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: ugg, that {} else {} was not suppose to be there. there was some other irrelevant-to-the question code there and my cut and paste job went awry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can have counter declared and incremented each time `blink` is called. then check if you have called `blink` three times, clear the interval. Also your `showNotice` function is not defined properly.

```
var counter = 0,
    timerId;

function blink() {
    if ($('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        if (counter > 4) {
            showNotice(false);
        }
    }
    counter++;
}

function showNotice(show) {
    if (show) {
        timerId = setInterval(blink, 200);
    } else {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        counter = 0;
    }
}

$('#addToCart').click(function () {
    if ($("select > option:first").is(":selected")) {
        showNotice(true);
    } else {
        showNotice(false);
        $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
})
```

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e5F7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function blink(){
    var blinkCount = 0;
    return function () {
        if($('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility')== 'hidden'){
            $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $('.pleaseSelect').css('visibility', 'hidden')
        }
        blinkCount = blinkCount + 1;
        if (blinkCount === 3) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
    }
}
```

the only thing is that timeId is global - bad practice... however you would have to refactor more of your code in order to correct that issue.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to just fadIn and fadeOut rather than what you're doing.

It would look something like:

```
if(element.val() == ''){
    element.fadeOut("fast");
    element.fadeIn("fast");
    element.fadeOut("fast");
    element.fadeIn("fast");
    element.fadeOut("fast");
    element.fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Comment: i will probably use this for the job, even though i dont select as 'the' answer here., thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/m8aXk/)?  Use an anonymous function to call your blink method and keep decrementing a counter.

```
    id = setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (!counter) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
        blink();
    }, 200);
```

See [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8aXk/) for the complete context.

Comment: I agree with @Chris , though.  You're kinda reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the desired behavior using variables within a private scope:

```
$('#addToCart').click(function(e) {
  blink(e);
});

function blink(e) {
  var blink_count = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(e) {
    blink_count++;
    $('.pleaseSelect').toggle();
    if (blink_count >= 6) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      blink_count = 0;
    }
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: I had originally had the code in there using the event target as the toggle selector before realizing you were toggling another element :)